# Shortest path within a list in Python

Tags: python

Suppose i have list as the following:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

And suppose i have the following requirements to choose the path:

```
starting_index = 3
ending_index = 7
```

Which means that get the items those starting from 3 to 7 which results:

```
first_path = [3,4,5,6,7]
```

Suppose that this is a circular list and this path can also be as:

```
second_path = [7,8,9,0,1,2,3]
```

In this case the following can solve the problem (shortest path):

```
shortest_path = a[3:7]
```

But for the requirements as follows:

```
starting_index = 1
ending_index = 8
```

From index 1 to 8 results:

```
first_path = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

But on the other hand:

```
second_path = [8,9,0,1]
```

So in this case:

```
shortest_path = a[1:8]
```

Does not solve the problem.
How can i automatize this problem?
Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

```
if len(a) - e_ind + s_ind > e_ind - s_ind:
    sp = a[s_ind:e_ind+1]
else:
    sp = a[e_ind:] + a[:s_ind+1]
```

Or more concise:

```
sp = a[s_ind:e_ind+1] if len(a) - e_ind + s_ind > e_ind - s_ind else a[e_ind:] + a[:s_ind+1]
```

Example:

```
>>> s_ind, e_ind = 3, 7
>>> sp
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

s_ind, e_ind = 1, 8
>>> sp
[8, 9, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `slice` method and `slice`s are comparable so you can use `min` on them:

```
shortest_path = (a+a)[min(slice(start, end+1), slice(end, len(a)+start+1))]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
start_to_end = slice(start, end+1)
end_to_start = slice(end, len(a)+start+1)

if start_to_end > end_to_start:
    shortest_path = (a+a)[start_to_end]
else:
    shortest_path = (a+a)[end_to_start]
```